# filling zero for missing time stamp in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, elasticsearch

I am reading data from elastic search and converting it into a df with below code:-

```
def elastic(domain):
    client = Elasticsearch(['10.0.0.10:9200/'],timeout=600)
    s = Search(using=client)
    s = s.query({"constant_score" : {
                "filter" : {
                     "bool" : {
                        "must" : [{
                  "range": {"@timestamp" : {
                    "gte": "now-7d",
                    "lte": "now"
                }}
              }],
                       "filter": [
                            {"term"  :{"type" :"vx_clientevents"}}, # 1st filter, get all the data where type is "vx_apache_json"
                            {"term"  :{"status_event" :"event"}},  # 2nd filter, get all the data where api is "viv_signin.php"
                            {"term"  :{"domain":domain}}# 3rd filter, get all the data where domain is "fnwp"    
                       ]         
                     }}}})
    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame((d.to_dict() for d in s.scan()))
        df['time']=df['@timestamp']
        df = df[['time', 'delta_count','status_event','ev']]
    except:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        
    return df
```

and then ai am resampling the data into 15 minute interval ;-

```
df = getdf("mt1cnp")
df = df.pivot_table(index='time', columns='status_event', values='delta_count', aggfunc='first', fill_value=0).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
df.set_index("time", inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15Min')).aggregate(np.sum)
df
```

[image]

So In seven days, we have 10080 minutes and as I am resampling the data in 15 minutes intervals I should have 672 observations but sometimes it's 300, 500, or 600, and sometimes even just one observation or even no observation.

I want to impute 0 for the missing timestamp data point. if the output df from elastic search has just one observation or no observation then I want to put 0 for even 15 minute time stamp.

Comment: elasticsearch provides data in microsecond so i am group it by 15 minute frequency

Comment: no its not because elastic search is not giving me data for that time frame.  so suppose I am reading data for now-7days but elastic search gave me data just for 6 days so that 1 day of data is missing totally

Comment: like suppose the 7th-day data is not there from the elastic search query then the next command will resample it in 15 minute interval

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should be created 15Min consecutive DatetimeIndex and for missing intervals are added `0`.

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15Min')).aggregate(np.sum)
```

Alternative is [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df = df.resample('15Min').sum()
```

If not, you can add [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df = df.asfreq('15Min', fill_value=0)
```